# prevent default behavior for an element on another element's event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel that contains a list of bootstrap switches, beside each there is a clockpicker.

what I want to do is, when the switch is changed to OFF, i want to prevent the default behavior (i.e. using `preventDefault()`) of the clockpicker so it is no longer triggerable.

I'm tried to simply disable the clockpicker, but it's not working at all:

```
$("#switch").change(function(){
if (this.checked == false)
{ $("#clockpicker1").prop("disabled", true") }
})
```

HTML structure for Clockpicker:

```
<li class="list-group-item-padding">
    <div class="input-group clockpicker" id="ddd" data-placement="left" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true">
        <input type="text" id="saturdayPicker1" class="form-control" value="15:00" />
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="saturdayPickerSpan1">
            <span id="saturdayIcon1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

HTML structure for switch:

```
<li class="list-group-item">Sunday
    <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="sundaySwitch" name="daySwitch" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="sundaySwitch" class="label-primary"></label>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: can you add the html structure as well...

Comment: @MayankRaj i've added the required html structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code has a syntax error, but it looks like you might have been using strings as the value with `prop`. You should use booleans for `disabled` (and `checked` and other boolean properties).

Responding to bootstrap-switch's `switchChange.bootstrapSwitch` event by setting the `disabled` property on the actual `input` for the clockpicker works:

```js
// Workaround for clockpicker bug:
// You must do this *BEFORE* you initialize the clockpickers
$(".clockpicker .input-group-addon").on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(this).closest(".clockpicker").find("input")[0].disabled) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
// End workaround

$(".clockpicker").clockpicker();
$("input[type=checkbox]").bootstrapSwitch().on("switchChange.bootstrapSwitch", function() {
  // Find the associated clockpicker
  var cp = $(this).closest(".switch-clock-container").find(".clockpicker");
  // Enable/disable its input
  cp.find("input").prop("disabled", this.checked);
  // If disabling, close it if it's open
  if (this.checked) {
    cp.clockpicker("hide");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/bootstrap-clockpicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/bootstrap-clockpicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch-clock-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox">
  <div class="input-group clockpicker">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="09:30">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="switch-clock-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox">
  <div class="input-group clockpicker">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="09:30">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on your solution still if u click on the gyphicon span element, the clockpicker appears even if the swith is on off mode

Comment: @AliAlhamaly: I'd report that as a bug in the clockpicker. But let's see if we can work around their bug...

Comment: @AliAlhamaly: Added workaround. You could probably also use the `beforeShow` callback assuming it lets you cancel the operation.

Comment: @AliAlhamaly: Can't say I think much of either bootstrap switch or clockpicker, frankly. I'm running into timing issues here, let's see if we can make the workaround more robust.

Comment: @AliAlhamaly: Yeah, the clockpicker documents a `beforeShow` but it doesn't call it (!). I've improved the workaround for the bug now, and also added code to hide the clockpicker if it's open when you switch the switch to Off. Seems to work well now.

Comment: Just to make things more clear, each switch there are two clockpickers beside,

Comment: And i want to disable both of them, think of it like both indicate (from-to)

Comment: @AliAlhamaly: Simple enough to modify the code above to handle both of the clockpickers, I leave that part to you. I've shown you how to disable one, and how to workaround the bug in the library.